# Notation for “either a value or the identity”

Tags: complex-analysis, field-theory, notation

I’m trying to take a fourth root as an exercise in a complex analysis book. The basic characteristic of a fourth root (I think) is that there is one pair of solutions +/- a, and another pair of solutions +/- a*i. I would much rather have to only write a out once, like +/-(i?) * a.

I’m looking for a compact notation similar to the +/- sign, which would express that there is one solution where the symbol represents the annotated value (in this case i), and another solution where the symbol represents the field’s identity value. Maybe something from category theory?

Comment: You can write $ae^{ki\pi/2}$ for $k\in\{0,1,2,3\}$. Not sure if that helps.

Comment: One way to describe the set of $n$th roots of a complex number is to pick any one of them, call it $b$, and form the set of numbers $\omega b$, where $\omega$ is a solution to $\omega^n = 1$ (and *not* to write out any formulas for the possible values of $\omega$). This is PC1's suggestion, except it does not single out any particular fourth root of $1$ for purposes of "writing out" the other fourth roots of $1$.)  This isn't as "explicit" as other approaches, but is sometimes conceptually clearer, e.g. it doesn't require recognition some more complex formula is describing $n$th roots of $1$.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I explicitly defined a symbol to represent the set {1, i}. I used the letter k, because I figured j might be too easily confused with i. The set can also be written as k = +sqrt(+/-1).